# What kind of screw should I use to affix plywood to a hollow metal door?

Tags: doors, screws, metal, plywood

I need to affix a plywood frame (depth ~1.25 cm or so) to an office entrance door. The door is metallic, but not a solid metal block: it's hollow. The metal face of the door is about 2mm. [This](http://www.rav-bariach.com/data/articals/designedsecuritydoors_462313071.pdf) is the kind of door I'm talking about (not this particular make or model, but that's the basic idea.

Which kind of screw should I use? And should I use  metal ring(s) somewhere?

Comment: how thick is the metal where you intend using screws? consider adding reinforcing plates...

Comment: @SolarMike: See edit.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using 4mm-width, 30mm length wood screws, i.e. screws with a conical head and a cross shaped recess (for Philips/Posidriv screwdrivers). So, something like the second from the right in this image:
[image]

I used a 3.3mm metal drilling bit - narrower than the screw. Since the metal is thin, and likely not very hard, I was expecting to be able to widen the bore using the screw itself, in a way that would help it fasten itself to the bore. I first drove my drill bit through the plywood frame; when I got to the door, I didn't try to push forward wil a lot of strength immediately, but rather leaned into the drill with mild extra force, and let it take a while to do its work. It took a good few seconds for the bit to go throw the outer metal layer.

I then drove the screw in with a powered screwdriver some of the way, then fastened manually. The fastening required a bit of strength; it compressed the plywood, so that more than the code now appeared sunken; and did seem to "catch" onto the metal - the most important point of the whole exercise.

I did not use any rings.

Comment: It would be usual to use a self-tapping screw, if you'll be doing more of this in the future.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: Can you link to an explanation of what that is? I'm not in an English-speaking country, so I might know it under a different name.

Comment: Here's Wikipedia's take on the subject: [Self-tapping screw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-tapping_screw). Also, I think that what you refer to as "rings" are known as [washers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washer_(hardware)) in English.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: How do self-tapping fasteners differ from those featured in the photo? Perhaps I was using a self-tapping screw  fastener already?

Comment: It would have been easier to drive the screw in. As what you did worked, there is nothing to worry about now.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: I'm saying that, from reading the article, it seems the screw I was using was "self-tapping". I can't figure out the difference. But never mind.